# Is there a way to make the same instance of the fragment open across the application no matter where it was called from (Drawe item or Button)

Tags: android, android-fragments

Hey everybody I've been struggling with this for a few days now. I have a fragment with a number of editTexts in it now in order to understand what is required from the user they must go to another fragment that inflates in the same layout, read what is in there and come back. Lets say the user have already filled some of the editTexts how do i retain them from getting wiped. All fragments are called from two places (Drawer menu item and another fragment that has all the buttons) if i open a fragment from the menu and re-open it from the menu the information is still there because it's already added to the backstack but if i open a fragment from the menu then go to the main fragment where all the buttons are and open the same fragment, its empty .. so it seems like I'm creating 2 backstacks? ... anybody knows a solution or know if that possible ?

MainActivity()

```
String itemName = fragment.getClass().getName();

  @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.

    int id = item.getItemId();


    if (id == R.id.menuItem1) {

        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        boolean FragmentOnePoppedMenu =manager.popBackStackImmediate(itemName, 0);
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fM = manager.beginTransaction();
       if(!FragmentOnePoppedMenu){

        fM.replace(R.id.content_main, fragment, mT);
           fM.addToBackStack(itemName);
        fM.commit();

       }
```

ButtonsFragment()

```
fragmentButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            FragmentManager manager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();


            boolean FragmentOnePoppedButton = manager.popBackStackImmediate(itemName, 0 );
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fM = manager.beginTransaction();

            if(!FragmentOnePoppedButton){

                fM.replace(R.id.content_main, fragment);
                fM.addToBackStack(itemName);
                fM.commit();
            }
```

Fragment()

```
View v =inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);

 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    if (savedInstanceState != null){
        editText1.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("text"), text);}

    else {}

    return v; }


 @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

outstate.putString("text", text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fragmets are supposed to be reusable accross your app. Check out **[Fragment.SavedState](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.SavedState.html)** to save the state of a Fragment to get the data you need later.

Here's an example

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putStr("someIndex", myIndex);
}
@Override
public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //savedInstanceState containes the saved data that now can retrived
}
```

So you can save the content of your Edit and then get it when the Fragment is opened again

Comment: I tried that, if(savedOnInstantSate !=null) and then set texts to all the editTexts but nothing happened

Comment: I mean if (SavedInstantState != null )

Comment: I added  Fragment()

Comment: @Redab0 what is `text` in `setText()` call?

Comment: editText1.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("NameOfText"), TextVariable);  where nameOfText is the name i pass when i add to the bundle in saveInstantSatet();

Comment: @Redab0 I am asking for the 2nd parameter

Comment: its a String from the same editText1 so  text = editText1.getText.toString(); if you're asking about setText("text", text") "text" is the name i passed for the variable while text is the actual variable